# COPY command failing when running DOCKER BUILD

Tags: docker

I'm trying to create a Docker image but it's not working. I'm trying to run this Docker command from the CLI and I'm getting the following error:

```
(from the <repo root>/src/Services/Accounts/Accounts.Api)
> docker build .
```

Error message:

```
Step 7/18 : COPY ["src/Services/Accounts/Accounts.Api/Accounts.Api.csproj", "src/Services/Accounts/Accounts.Api/"]
COPY failed: stat /var/lib/docker/tmp/docker-builder937056687/src/Services/Accounts/Accounts.Api/Accounts.Api.csproj: no such file or directory
```

and here's my Dockerfile

```
FROM microsoft/dotnet:2.1-aspnetcore-runtime AS base
WORKDIR /app
EXPOSE 80

FROM microsoft/dotnet:2.1-sdk AS build
WORKDIR /src
RUN  ls -al
COPY ["src/Services/Accounts/Accounts.Api/Accounts.Api.csproj", "src/Services/Accounts/Accounts.Api/"]
COPY ["src/Services/Accounts/Accounts.Api/NuGet.config", "src/Services/Accounts/Accounts.Api/"]

RUN dotnet restore "src/Services/Accounts/Accounts.Api/Accounts.Api.csproj"
COPY . .
WORKDIR "/src/src/Services/Accounts/Accounts.Api"
RUN dotnet build "Accounts.Api.csproj" -c Release -o /app

FROM build AS publish
RUN dotnet publish "Accounts.Api.csproj" -c Release -o /app

FROM base AS final
WORKDIR /app
COPY --from=publish /app .
ENTRYPOINT ["dotnet", "Hornet.Accounts.Api.dll"]
```

I've also tried running this from the repo root directory:

```
> docker build .\src\Services\Accounts\Accounts.Api
```

Why is it trying to find my files in some `/var/lib/docker/tmp/blah` folder?

Further info:

- Windows 10 OS
- Docker CE with Linux Containers
- VSCode

Comment: For `COPY` to work, the file from your end you are trying to copy (eg. `./src/Services/Accounts/Accounts.Api/Accounts.Api.csproj`) has to be in the build's context. Obviously it's missing. Kindly read how [image building process](https://docs.docker.com/engine/reference/commandline/build/#examples) works, especially what is the [build context](https://www.google.com/search?q=docker+build+context). I'm also assuming you know what's [COPY](https://docs.docker.com/engine/reference/builder/#copy) used for and how it works.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

I think we can solve this by clarifying how to use the build context and how to specify the location of the Dockerfile.

The Docker build command usage looks like this:

`docker build [OPTIONS] PATH`

Your build context is the location that you define with `PATH`, Docker can use the files in the build context for the build. (You cannot use files outside the build context for the build.)

In the Dockerfile in your `COPY` statements you are specifying the source files' location relative to the root of your repo. This implies that

**You should run your build command from the `<root of your repo>` with `PATH` `.` like this:**

`docker build .`

You have not specified the path of your Dockerfile in the question, but it seems to me that it's in a subfolder of your repo. To make your build work issue the docker build command from the `<root of your repo>` like this:

`docker build -f <path to Dockerfile> .`

Your Dockerfile must be in the build context.

**I think getting the build context and the location of the Dockerfile right will fix your build.**

Also remember to use the `-t` flag to tag your image.

> Why is it trying to find my files in some /var/lib/docker/tmp/blah folder?

As you probably know, Docker uses a Linux VM under the hood in the Docker for Windows app to develop Linux based containers. This location simply refers to the location in the VM.

Comment: Sweet - thank you @mark :) I was misunderstanding my usage of the `.` argument I was providing. I thought that was the local of the FOLDER to look for the Dockerfile ... but it's the `PATH` to the `build context`. gotcha :) sweet thank you.